# Disable Pagination on Pages

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have a strange request I thought would be simple. I need to break the Wordpress pagination. Specifically, I need to make the `/page/2/`, `/page/3/`, and so on, links disabled.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^page/[0-9] http://www.mysite[dot]com/404.php [R]
```

But that is a no go...
Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: This should be possible entirely within PHP/WordPress using rewrite rules ( modification of rewrite rules ), enabling an answer that works via a plugin across Nginx and Apache, as well as others. HTAccess knowledge shouldn't be needed or necessary

Comment: Also keep in mind that anybody can add the pagination query params manually to the end of the URL and continue using paging, it's not enough to disable the pretty URLs

Comment: Have you tried with the L flag, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nick! I thought that would work, and I placed it right after "RewriteEngine On" so it came first.

I did find a working solution for handling it though (after 2 hrs):

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /$1 [G]
```

In case anyone else needs to do the same ...

Answer (score 0):

That rule looks OK; the problem might be where you put it. Order matters in .htaccess, so be sure you're putting it in the right place. Check out this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476654/add-url-rewrite-rule-to-wordpress) thread.